# Force re-authentication using onelogin as SP and IDP

Tags: onelogin

I'm trying to force a re-authentication using SAML and Onelogin as the IDP, and the onelogin java lib for the SP.
For certain functions I would like to trigger a re-authentication, before the user can proceed.

First time user logs in to my application he must enter his credentials. After that he is logged in. But when I try to send an AuthnRequest, the user is immediately redirected back to my application without having to enter his credentials again.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ONELOGIN_xxx" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-11-07T12:31:09Z" ForceAuthn="true" Destination="https://myapp.onelogin.com/client/apps/select/xxx" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://local.my.app:8443">
    <saml:Issuer>local.my.app</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" AllowCreate="true" />
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

How can I force the user to re-enter his credentials again?

Answer (score 0):

Try including ForceAuthn="true" in the SAML request.